# Python Linkedin API Error

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve information from linkedin api and i am using the library python- linkedin

I paste the following link on to the browser. 
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile

replacing client_id with mine and the call_back_uri is http://localhost:8000
After that I get an authorization_code, I used it to get access token:

```
authentication.authorization_code = '******'
authentication.get_access_token()
```

I get an access token

```
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token='AQTFtPILQkJzXHrHtyQ0rjLe3W0I')
```

But when I tried to search the api with the following code:

```
application.search_profile(selectors=[{'people': ['first-name', 'last-name']}], params={'keywords': 'apple microsoft'})
```

I got this error. 
e-packages\linkedin\utils.py", line 63, in raise_for_error

```
    raise LinkedInError(message)
linkedin.exceptions.LinkedInError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/job-search:(jobs:(id,customer-job-code,posting-date))?count=2&oauth2_access_token=*******--Az_cToYEo7WkV7_GoAniWXrBYherCNni90jjGBFsTNpwZ8XsO4yLzTOyiXVfCFavXQ34nXi--kjwSVZEs1EVV3GmPYIJqyB7EcQMs0GZFovKlxE3cInSsIKchvAlEZB6GAkR7KdjI1itFBhvGCAPEdkK3Fd_AKhPEoLNnJO1nGbfUBnySMjkCENviksF8BODqT8O7KUvRG2iLwip3JpKneHg66J3zf8ZZjjaHHMChbbI9PVX135eS7RPofRvJw7KJ3-3IpGu-RhhB2lc2ecVIPcZQ0YV_KhV7eD5VzUWjzKAYjXGC5-rrabqqw&title=developer: Unknown Error
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?. Thank you.